# Connect to elasticsearch 6.4 running in Docker from golang host application

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, go, docker-compose, elasticsearch-6

Go ES client https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v6 throws the "no active connection found: no Elasticsearch node available" error when attempting to connect from OS X host to ES running in docker container.
There's many discussions on how to solve it in v5.*, however, I couldn't find anything for v6.4.

Docker-compose part:

```
elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:6.4.2
    network_mode: "bridge"
    expose:
      - "9200"
      - "9300"
    volumes:
      - ./es-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
```

Go client call:

```
esClient, esClientErr :=             
elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetURL("http://127.0.0.1:9200"))
if esClientErr != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to connect to ES: %v", esClientErr)
}
```

Output:

```
2018/11/09 15:57:54 Failed to connect to ES: no active connection found: no Elasticsearch node available
exit status 1
```

**UPDATE**

Setting `network.publish_host: "_local_"` solved the problem. The `publish_address` is set to `127.0.0.1:9300` now.

Comment: Is the ES server actually running?  Can you `curl` the same URL?

Comment: Yes, and Kibana successfully connects to it. But the client tries to hit the publish_address value which is set to docker network (172.17.0.2:9300). The question is how to configure it correspondingly.

Comment: `-E network.publish_host=_docker0_` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/modules-network.html#advanced-network-settings

Comment: Could you share the output of `curl http://127.0.0.1:9200`?